# Combine app.createServer and app.use

Tags: node.js, express

I'm writing a Nodejs app with express. I want to have persistent sessions (I want to use  socket.io later) with each client. 
I use `app.createServer()` to receive requests from a client. Is it possible to put `app.use()` inside `createServer()` instead of manually parsing the request and using a `switch-case` to forward it to each route ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're mixing [`http`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) with Express in a strange way.

A typical Express app looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var server  = app.listen(3000);

app.use(...);
app.use(...);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  return res.send('hello world');
});
```

As you can see, there's no need for `createServer()` or manual request parsing.

To implement persistent sessions, you could use [`express-session`](https://github.com/expressjs/session) with one of its [persisting stores](https://github.com/expressjs/session#compatible-session-stores).